# How to use values-hi in android studio?

Tags: android

I want to use hindi and marathi language in my android app , for that I created a new **values-hi** folder by right clicking on res and then **New -> Android Resource Directory ->** Locale and added hindi and selected any region , inside values-hi I created **strings.xml** file and declared a string
One

What i wanted to ask is , will the One be displayed in Hindi or English inside string.xml , and when i set it to textview it says

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f06000d

What else do i need to do ?

Need some help please

Answer (score 0):

You faced

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f06000d
```

because you should put it in original string.xml file and then put the same string in the translation file.

and if you need to create new file don't create new folder, just right click on values directory and then choose new value resource file, choose type as local then language and region and save.